# WP-CLI - How to install a plugin from a remote server

Tags: wp-cli

I'm trying to install a plugin that i downloaded and i host on my server inside a vagrant box to use locally.

I'm running this command to try to install it:

```
wp plugin install https://example.com/hosted/plugin.zip
```

but it fails with this error:

> Downloading install package from
>   example.com/hosted/plugin.zip...
>   Warning: Download failed. "stream_socket_client(): SSL operation
>   failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
>   stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
>   stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://example.com:443 (Unknown error)" Error: No plugins
>   installed.

It's clear to me that the issue is because the site is using an ssl certificate and the wp-cli can't trust it, but how can i solve this? how do i make the wp-cli trust the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`wp plugin install https://example.tld/path-to-zip-file/file.zip`

This fails because example.com port 443 was blocked or example.com may be have no SSL certificate.

If you try now, you will get

`Warning: Download failed. "Not Found"
Error: No plugins installed.`